# How to simplify label printing alignment configuration?

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, printing, jasper-reports

Using JSP and Jasper Reports, I made an application for printing A4 label pages.

I have to configure my application (set alignment on the PDF page to be generated) according to different pages (2×5, 2×7, 3×10 and 3×11 grids), different printers (Kyocera, OKI and HP) and different PDF viewers (Adobe, Foxit and Nitro).

***Example: I set in Jasper Reports an A4 page with a grid of 2×5 and an user who has Foxit Reader will print it on a Kyocera. If another user has Kyocera too but is using Adobe Reader, the space between the columns gets smaller. But if the user has Foxit Reader but will print on an OKI, the whole document goes left and even gets cut.***

To configure each individual label page is unavoidable, but can it be possible for me not have to set the page alignment for specific PDF viewer or printer (at least one of those)? It can be a way to skip the PDF generation or some conventional configuration that all printers would interpret - to get my page printed exactly the same, regardless of PDF viewer or printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this is not a setting in Foxit Reader and/or Adobe reader that is causing the issue?

I know in Adobe reader there is a setting in the print dialog under `Page Sizing & Handling`. They should use `Actual Size` so as to not do any scaling or manipulation of the image.

[image: Adobe Reader - Page Sizing & Handling]

In Foxit Reader it is under `Print Handling`. You need to set Scaling Type to `None`. The default seems to be `Fit to Printer Margins`.

[image: Foxit Reader - Print Handling]

You should not have to do anything different for each PDF reader and/or each version and combination of printer. That is a maintenance nightmare you should not try to take this on. You would have to make changes every time they bought a new printer, and potentially when an upgrade to their reader comes out.

Best bet is to figure out why they are producing different results, and tackle that issue, instead of brute forcing the problem. I am pretty sure this is more a training issue with your users, and telling them about these settings should clear up the problem.

---

**UPDATE:** After some more digging it seems to be possible to set the value of the Print Scaling while exporting. After you create your `JRPdfExporter` you need to set [`JRPdfExporterParameter.PRINT_SCALING`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporterParameter.html#PRINT_SCALING) to [`JRPdfExporterParameter.PRINT_SCALING_NONE`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporterParameter.html#PRINT_SCALING_NONE):

```
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PRINT_SCALING, JRPdfExporterParameter.PRINT_SCALING_NONE);
```

I do not know if this will work for Foxit Reader also, but I would assume it would.